# how we set more than one splash screens using Phonegap android apps

Tags: android, cordova

how we set more than one splash screens ,while open apps it should different splash screen using phonegap in android apps .let assume If there are three splash screen scr1.png,scr2.png,scr3.png,Now i want to show first splash screen if apps open first time and second time ,show splash screen scr2.png... , it should be change rotationally if your apps open . Using phonegap only is it possible ?

Comment: I don't know why you want to implement this type of behaviour.This is irrespective of logic.This does not make any sense.

Comment: U ll have to make changes into native app..it will be easier than to make changes in javascript